# Why does barrier synchronize shared memory when memoryBarrier doesn't?

Tags: glsl

The following GLSL compute shader simply copies `inImage` to `outImage`. It is derived from a more complex post-processing pass.

In the first several lines of `main()`, a single thread loads 64 pixels of data into the shared array. Then, after synchronizing, each of the 64 threads writes one pixel to the output image.

Depending on how I synchronize, I get different results. I originally thought `memoryBarrierShared()` would be the correct call, but it produces the following result:

[image: Unsynchronized result]

which is the same result as having no synchronization or using `memoryBarrier()` instead.

If I use `barrier()`, I get the following (desired) result:

[image]

The striping is 32 pixels wide, and if I change the workgroup size to anything less than or equal to 32, I get correct results.

What's going on here? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `memoryBarrierShared()`? Why should `barrier()` work?

```
#version 430

#define SIZE 64

layout (local_size_x = SIZE, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(rgba32f) uniform readonly  image2D inImage;
uniform writeonly image2D outImage;

shared vec4 shared_data[SIZE];

void main() {
    ivec2 base = ivec2(gl_WorkGroupID.xy * gl_WorkGroupSize.xy);
    ivec2 my_index = base + ivec2(gl_LocalInvocationID.x,0);

    if (gl_LocalInvocationID.x == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            shared_data[i] = imageLoad(inImage, base + ivec2(i,0));
        }
    }

    // with no synchronization:   stripes
    // memoryBarrier();        // stripes
    // memoryBarrierShared();  // stripes
    // barrier();              // works

    imageStore(outImage, my_index, shared_data[gl_LocalInvocationID.x]);
}
```

Comment: How do you then display it? Maybe the compute shader works correctly, but the image itself is not synchronized between the compute shader invocation and the following display, i.e. what about an appropriate `glMemoryBarrier` on the host side (not sure about that, though).

Comment: I'm using a library that wraps OpenGL and is handling all of the communication with the GPU. It's thus difficult to incorporate the display code into my MWE. Since I also get correct results when allowing each thread to perform a single `imageLoad` followed by an `imageStore`, I don't think host-device synchronization is the issue.

Comment: *"Since I also get correct results when allowing each thread to perform a single imageLoad followed by an imageStore, I don't think host-device synchronization is the issue."* - Well, if it is really the inter-pass synchronization that fails, then a side effect of undefined behaviour is, that it may very well work for certain configurations. `glMemoryBarrier` is still a device-device synchronization, not host-device.

Comment: You're of course right that undefined behavior may work in certain configurations. In any case, I threw glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS) between my pass and the following pass, with no change in the results.

Comment: Digged further, seems you need the `barrier`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem with image load store and friends is, that the implementation cannot be sure anymore that a shader only changes the data of it's dedicated output values (e.g. the framebuffer after a fragment shader). This applies even more so to compute shaders, which don't have a dedicated output, but only output things by writing data into writable store, like images, storage buffers or atomic counters. This may require manual synchronization between individual passes as otherwise the fragment shader trying to access a texture might not have the most recent data written into that texture with image store operations by a preceding pass, like your compute shader.

So it may be that your compute shader works perfectly, but it is the synchronization with the following display (or whatever) pass (that needs to read this image data somehow) that fails. For this purpose there exists the [`glMemoryBarrier`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMemoryBarrier) function. Depending on how you read that image data in the display pass (or more precisely the pass that reads the image after the compute shader pass), you need to give a different flag to this function. If you read it using a texture, use `GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT​`, if you use an image load again, use `GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT​`, if using `glBlitFramebuffer` for display, use `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BARRIER_BIT​`...

Though I don't have much experience with image load/store and manual memory snynchronization and this is only what I came up with theoretically. So if anyone knows better or you already use a proper `glMemoryBarrier`, then feel free to correct me. Likewise does this not need to be your only error (if any). But the last two points from the linked Wiki article actually address your use case and IMHO make it clear that you need some kind of `glMemoryBarrier`:

> - Data written to image variables in one rendering pass and read by the shader in a later pass need not use `coherent` variables or
>     `memoryBarrier()`. Calling `glMemoryBarrier` with the
>     `SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT​` set in barriers​ between passes is
>     necessary.
> - Data written by the shader in one rendering pass and read by another mechanism (e.g., vertex or index buffer pulling) in a later pass need
>     not use `coherent` variables or `memoryBarrier()`. Calling
>     `glMemoryBarrier` with the appropriate bits set in barriers​ between
>     passes is necessary.

---

**EDIT:** Actually the [Wiki article on compute shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader) says

> Shared variable access uses the rules for incoherent memory access.
>   This means that the user must perform certain synchronization in order
>   to ensure that shared variables are visible.
>
> Shared variables are all implicitly declared `coherent​`, so you don't
>   need to (and can't use) that qualifier. However, you still need to
>   provide an appropriate memory barrier.
>
> The usual set of memory barriers is available to compute shaders, but
>   they also have access to `memoryBarrierShared()​;` this barrier is
>   specifically for shared variable ordering. `groupMemoryBarrier()`​
>   acts like `memoryBarrier()​`, ordering memory writes for all kinds of
>   variables, but it only orders read/writes for the current work group.
>
> **While all invocations within a work group are said to execute "in parallel", that doesn't mean that you can assume that all of them are
>   executing in lock-step. If you need to ensure that an invocation has
>   written to some variable so that you can read it, you need to
>   synchronize execution with the invocations, not just issue a memory
>   barrier (you still need the memory barrier though).**
>
> **To synchronize reads and writes between invocations within a work group, you must employ the `barrier()`​ function. This forces an
>   explicit synchronization between all invocations in the work group.
>   Execution within the work group will not proceed until all other
>   invocations have reach this barrier. Once past the `barrier()​`, all
>   shared variables previously written across all invocations in the
>   group will be visible.**

So this actually sounds like you need the `barrier` there and the `memoryBarrierShared` is not enough (though you don't need both, as the last sentence says). The memory barrier will just synchronize the *memory*, but it doesn't stop the *execution* of the threads to cross it. Thus the threads won't read any old cached data from the shared memory *if* the first thread has already written something, but they can very well reach the point of reading *before* the first thread has tried to write anything at all.

This actually fits perfectly to the fact that for 32 and below block sizes it works and that the first 32 pixels work. At least on NVIDIA hardware 32 is the warp size and thus the number of threads that operate in perfect lock-step. So the first 32 threads (well, every block of 32 threads) always work exactly parallel (well, conceptually that is) and thus they cannot introduce any race-conditions. This is also the case why you don't actually need any synchronization if you know you work inside a single warp, a common optimization.