# Sample depth buffer in OpenGL compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu

I'm trying to sample a depth texture into a compute shader and to copy it into an other texture.

The problem is that I don't get correct values when I read from the depth texture:

I've tried to check if the initial values of the depth texture were correct (with GDebugger), and they are. So it's the imageLoad GLSL function that retrieve wrong values.

This is my GLSL Compute shader:

```
layout (binding=0, r32f) readonly uniform image2D depthBuffer;
layout (binding=1, rgba8) writeonly uniform image2D colorBuffer;

// we use 16 * 16 threads groups
layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;

void    main()
{
    ivec2       position = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    // Sampling from the depth texture
    vec4        depthSample = imageLoad(depthBuffer, position);
    // We linearize the depth value
    float       f = 1000.0;
    float       n = 0.1;
    float       z = (2 * n) / (f + n - depthSample.r * (f - n));
    // even if i try to call memoryBarrier(), barrier() or memoryBarrierShared() here, i still have the same bug
    // and finally, we try to create a grayscale image of the depth values
    imageStore(colorBuffer, position, vec4(z, z, z, 1));
}
```

and this is how I'm creating the depth texture and the color texture:

```
// generate the deth texture
glGenTextures(1, &_depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _depthTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, wDimensions.x, wDimensions.y, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

// generate the color texture
glGenTextures(1, &_colorTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _colorTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, wDimensions.x, wDimensions.y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

I fill the depth texture with depth values (bind it to a frame buffer and render the scene) and then I call my compute shader this way:

```
_computeShader.use();

// try to synchronize with the previous pass
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
// even if i call glFinish() here, the result is the same

glBindImageTexture(0, _depthTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_R32F);
glBindImageTexture(1, _colorTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA8);

glDispatchCompute((wDimensions.x + WORK_GROUP_SIZE - 1) / WORK_GROUP_SIZE,
                  (wDimensions.y + WORK_GROUP_SIZE - 1) / WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 1); // we divide the compute into groups of 16 threads

// try to synchronize with the next pass
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
```

with:

1. wDimensions = size of the context (and of the framebuffer)
2. WORK_GROUP_SIZE = 16

Do you have any idea of why I don't get valid depth values?

EDIT:

This is what the color texture looks like when I render a sphere:

[image]

and it seems that glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) doesn't do anything:
Even if I call it just before the glDispatchCompute() I still have the same image...
How can this be possible?

Comment: For one thing: `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` is not a floating-point image format. It is fixed-point (e.g. `GL_R16`). There is only 1 floating-point depth image format (well 2 if you count packed depth+stencil) and that is 32-bit: `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`

Comment: You are right, now i get values but they seem not good.

Comment: *How can this be possible?* Lots of really weird things happen if you do not use memory barriers with compute shaders. Since they access memory in a very general purpose fashion it is difficult for GL to properly schedule and synchronize operations that need to complete before/after the compute shader. The normal graphics pipeline has a clear definition of which operations are dependent, etc. compute shaders totally break this since they are not an actual stage in the graphics pipeline but completely independent.

Comment: Well, i've tried to add `glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);` before and after the glDispactchCompute() but it doesn't change anything.

I guess i didn't really understand how glMemoryBarrier works...

Comment: I think you also need to use memory barriers in the compute shader itself to 100% ensure everything. However what you could definately try, if you are not doing so yet, is to run OpenGL in Debug Mode, this may expose additional errors.

Comment: Well i use CodeXL to check the OpenGL errors and i have one on the `glLinkProgram()` of my rendering shaders but the call to `glGetProgramiv(_progId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkRet);` just after returns GL_TRUE, so i guess it's an error from CodeXL. And i have no idea of how to call memoryBarrier in the compute shader. I have read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430443/why-does-barrier-synchronize-shared-memory-when-memorybarrier-doesnt) and i've tried to call the different functions before the imageStore (memoryBarrier, memoryBarrierShared, barrier) but i still have the bug.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Another bad Archive.org pull :(

Comment: Thanks for paying attention! I had already updated the script, but forgot that this is controlled by an external file with 404 images which isn't part of the source code. I have a list of all repaired images the script has repaired, I'll doublecheck those soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, i discovered that you cannot send a depth texture as an image to a compute shader, even with the readonly keyword.

So i've replaced:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, _depthTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_R32F);
```

by:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _depthTexture);
```

and in my compute shader:

```
layout (binding=0, r32f) readonly uniform image2D depthBuffer;
```

by:

```
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D depthBuffer;
```

and to sample it i just write:

```
ivec2       position = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
vec2        screenNormalized = vec2(position) / vec2(ctxSize); // ctxSize is the size of the depth and color textures
vec4        depthSample = texture2D(depthBuffer, screenNormalized);
```

and it works very well like this

Comment: Can you please tell me where you found that you cannot send depth textures as image2D? I'm in a similar situation, but I want to WRITE to the depth texture, so sampler2D won't work for me.

Comment: I noticed also this strange behavior to not be able to use the depthbuffer as an image2D. But i can't find an official note that you shouldn't it -.-

Comment: @Makx It doesn't explicitly say. However, the `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT*` formats are not among the ones listed to be supported by `glBindImageTexture` https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml