# How to use atomic operations on an SSBO in a compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu-atomics

## Example code

Here is a bare-bones compute shader to illustrate my question

```
layout(local_size_x = 64) in;

// Persistent LIFO structure with a count of elements
layout(std430, binding = 0) restrict buffer SMyBuffer
{
    int count;
    float data[];
} MyBuffer;

bool AddDataElement(uint i);
float ComputeDataElement(uint i);

void main()
{
    for (uint i = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x; i < some_end_condition; i += gl_WorkGroupSize.x)
    {
        if (AddDataElement(i))
        {
            // We want to store this data piece in the next available free space
            uint dataIndex = atomicAdd(MyBuffer.count, 1);
            // [1] memoryBarrierBuffer() ?
            MyBuffer.data[dataIndex] = ComputeDataElement(i);
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

`SMyBuffer` is a stack of elements (`data[]`) with a `count` of the current number of elements. When a certain condition is met, the compute shader increments the count atomically. This operation returns the previous index which is used to index `data[]` to store the new element. This guarantees that no two shader invocations overwrite each other's elements.

Another compute shader eventually pops values from this stack and uses them. `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` is of course required between the two compute shader dispatches.

## Question

All this works fine but I'm wondering if I'm just being lucky with timings and I want to validate my usage of the API.

So, is anything else required to make sure that the counter stored in the SSBO works (see [1](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Internal_visibility))? I'm expecting `atomicAdd()` takes care of the memory synchronization because otherwise it makes little sense. What would be the point of an atomic operation whose effect is only visible in a single thread?

Regarding memory barriers, the [OpenGL wiki states](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Internal_visibility):

> Note that atomic counters are different functionally from atomic image/buffer variable operations. The latter still need coherent qualifiers, barriers, and the like.

which leaves me wondering whether there's something I haven't understood properly and a `memoryBarrierBuffer()` is actually required. But then if that is the case, what's to stop 2 threads from performing `atomicAdd()` before one of them gets to the subsequent `memoryBarrierBuffer()`?

Also, does the answer change whether `glDispatchCompute()` dispatches a single workgroup or more?

Comment: An interesting related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430443/why-does-barrier-synchronize-shared-memory-when-memorybarrier-doesnt

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340333/glsl-about-coherent-qualifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `memoryBarrierBuffer()` call as the `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` will stall any reads that your second shader (the consumer) issues until all the writes from your first shader are completed.
The number of workgroups dispatched does not change the answer as all the writes from the `glDispatchCompute()` will need to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question revolves around competing atomic read-write operations in the first shader from parallel shader executions of it. The `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` does indeed take care of insuring that the second shader waits for all writes from the first shader to finish.

Comment: atomicAdd also takes care of the barriers required to make the change visible to any other thread in the system.