# If a `buffer` is `coherent`, is there any difference between reading a field or doing `atomicAdd(field, 0)`?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

This is with Vulkan semantics, if it makes any difference.

Assume the following:

```
layout(...) coherent buffer B
{
    uint field;
} b;
```

Say the field is being modified by other invocations of the same shader (or a derived shader) through `atomic*()` funcions.

If a shader invocation wants to perform an atomic read from this `field` (with the same semantics as `atomicCounter()` in GLES, had this been an `atomic_uint` instead), is there any difference between the following two (other than obviously that one of them does a write as well as read)?

```
uint read_value = b.field;
uint read_value2 = atomicAdd(b.field, 0);
```

Comment: This question needs more details. For example, what does "enough" mean? "Enough" to perform what operation? `coherent` has a meaning relative to a pair of operations. What operation do you want to make the atomic access `coherent` with? What is the relationship between these two operations? And so forth. The question as stated just doesn't contain sufficient information.

Comment: It's emulating atomic counters, so `coherent` with other `atomicAdd` operations on the same `uint` (that emulate `atomicCounterIncrement` and `atomicCounterDecrement`).

Comment: Other `atomicAdd` operations *where*? In the same shader stage? In derived shader stages? In shader stages from subsequent rendering commands? Saying that you're "emulating atomic counters" says nothing about the actual operations you're doing.

Comment: Obviously subsequent rendering commands need other barriers. I was asking about other invocations of the same shader (as hinted in one of the question items). I hadn't thought about derived shader stages, I would be curious to know if that makes a difference (maybe on tiling GPUs?). --- Sorry I wasn't being more specific, I assumed it's quite obvious how `atomic_uint` would be emulated with a `buffer AC { uint counters[]; } ac;`

Comment: And my point is that how you emulate it depends on your use case. There's no one-size-fits-all solution here.

Comment: I feel like my itemized questions are actually quite independent of emulating atomic counters. For example, I'm asking if a buffer is `coherent` and you read from it as well as `atomic*()` on it, could the read value be cached more locally than the result of the atomic operations. A yes/no answer to that (and the other question) would give me enough information to know what I need to know to do the emulation.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question to not mention the atomic counters.

Comment: And what does "cached more locally" mean with regard to actual behavior?

Comment: Say if the `atomicAdd(field)`'s result (written value) is stored in L2, and reading `field` results in it getting cached in L1 (causing future modifications by other invocations not to be visible), that would be more local (which is apparently not the right terminology).

Comment: My point is that this is a matter of specific implementation, not *behavior*. The meaning of `coherent` is defined in terms of behavior, the relationship between reads and writes from and to various locations. Implementations have to work out the details of caches to make that implementation happen. And those details will be specific to the implementation, not something that is generally useful.

Comment: Right, I meant to ask for the behavior of `coherent`, but was thinking about how it's implemented. So, is the question understandable now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPIR-V has an [`OpAtomicLoad`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#OpAtomicLoad) instruction. Presumably, there is at least one piece of hardware in which non-atomic loads cannot replace an atomic load no matter what qualifier the buffer descriptor has.

Unfortunately, there is no Vulkan GLSL construct that can translate to `OpAtomicLoad` that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question, those two lines of code generate different instructions, with differing performance characteristics and hardware pipeline usage.

```
uint read_value = b.field;                 // generates a load instruction
uint read_value2 = atomicAdd(b.field, 0);  // generates an atomic instruction
```

- [AMD disassembly can be seen in this online Shader Playground](http://shader-playground.timjones.io/0733f88ba4b8ddd197c0242b1273044d) -- `buffer_load_dword` versus `buffer_atomic_add`
- [Dissecting the NVIDIA Volta GPU Architecture via Microbenchmarking](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06826) -- `LDG` versus `ATOM`

The [GLSL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) section 4.10 Memory Qualifiers makes a point that `coherent` is only about visibility of reads and writes across invocations (shader threads).  They also left a comment on the implied performance:

> When accessing memory using variables not declared as coherent, the memory accessed by a shader may be cached by the implementation to service future accesses to the same address.  Memory stores may be cached in such a way that the values written might not be visible to other shader invocations accessing the same memory.  The implementation may cache the values fetched by memory reads and return the same values to any shader invocation accessing the same memory, even if the underlying memory has been modified since the first memory read.  While variables not declared as coherent might not be useful for communicating between shader invocations, using non-coherent accesses may result in higher performance.

The point-of-coherence in GPU memory systems is usually the last-level cache (L2 cache), meaning all coherent accesses must be performed by the L2 cache.  This also means coherent buffers cannot be cached in L1 or other caches closer to the shader processors.  Modern GPUs also have dedicated atomic hardware in the L2 caches; a plain load will not use those, but an `atomicAdd(..., 0)` will go through those.  The atomic hardware usually has lower bandwidth than the full L2 cache.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I do realize they generate different assembly. My question was really about whether they could **potentially** "behave" differently. In other words, is it guaranteed that just reading the variable always returns the same value as `atomicAdd(var, 0)`? I'm getting more convinced that it is.

Comment: BTW, I'm very intimately familiar with GCN, and under that architecture I can tell they would be equivalent (with some driver assumptions). What I'm looking for is a spec guarantee that this would always be the case. I guess your quote is indirectly saying this: _"When accessing memory using variables not declared as coherent, the memory accessed by a shader may be cached by the implementation to service future accesses to the same address."_ So (!coherent => cached) although mathematically we can't deduce that (coherent => !cached), but I would pin that more on poor wording.